Python Relative and Absolute Imports not Working
I have a file structure like this:
└── scraper
    ├── __init__.py
    └── converter
        ├── items.py
        ├──__init__.py
        └── spiders
            ├──__init__.py
            └──spider.py

I am in spider.py and I'm trying to import items.py, I'm doing it like this:
from .. import items

and getting the error:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package 

so I thought of specifying the parent directory:
from ...converter import items

but got the same error.
I then switched to absolute imports:
from scraper.converter import items

and got this error:
No module named 'scraper'

What the hell???

How do you execute the code?

I currently execute the spider.py file directly

Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py

@mkrieger1 Yes, I just read that but I'm still struggling to understandd what I'm doing wrong

You are using relative imports in a file that is executed as a script.

In your latest edit, you seem to be executing the script in an environment where scraper is not in the Python module search path.

I'm executing the file 'spider.py' from visual studio code's 'Run and Debug'

Pretty much every issue with relative imports boils down to ignoring the difference between a script and a module.

@chepner I'm quite sure that is my case. If I understand correctly, any file that is in the same folder of an __init__.py file will be considered a module.

No, files are just files. What matters is how Python tries to use the files: a script is executed directly; a module is imported. When you write import foo, the import system (usually) looks for a file named foo.py in a directory listed in sys.path. Directories don't really need __init__.py to mark them as packages anymore.

you need to create __init__.py files in any folder where you want to import a python module from
from your root project dir you could do something like
for d in $(find ./ -type d); do
  touch "$d/__init__.py"
done

in shell

I just edited the post to show the actual file structure, I didn't think init.py files were important

P.S. The init.py files are currently empty

Relative imports in Python are indeed primarily intended for use within packages. When you import modules from within the package or from sub-packages, relative imports allow you to specify the module's location relative to the current module. So the __init__.py are actually important for the case

@baskettaz So should I write something in the init files?

no, they could be empty, but are for some peculiar reason relevant for the relative imports

anything you write in the __init__.py will be processed when the module is referenced

__init__.py is used to provide code for a module when that module is also a package. It's been a very long time since you needed to add an empty __init__.py to mark a directory as a package.

You need to execute from the root of your project using the -m switch (VS should have an option for this). As in
$ python -m scraper.converter.spiders.spider # note no .py

Then the imports you wrote should all work correctly

If I execute this command from outside the 'scraper' folder I get No module named 'scraper'. If I do it from inside the 'scraper' folder I get No module named scraper.converter.spiders.spider

Also, keep in mind I would like to avoid executing my code from cmd

You should execute from the parent dir of scraper @Rodolfo - make sure the module path reflects the directory structure (I took it from the question - also all init files must be present). VS should have an option for its run configuration to use the -m switch (Pycharm does) - this is the standard way for executing a srcipt I hope they do.
